# Informatica PowerCenter: does anyone know a way of using the keyboard instead of mouse pointer in Edit Tasks in Workflow Designer?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In Informatica PowerCenter I'm looking for ways to make less use of the mouse, and more of the keyboard keys.

In the Workflow Designer, when editting a task, I'd like to 'jump' from value of connection to the other value of connection, and change the connection type, with only using the keyboard, and not by using the mouse pointer. Now I have to click on the downarrow of the first connection, and then use the mouse to go to the second downarrow, etc. I can't imagine it is not possible, but so far I tried without succes.

Jumping from connection to connection IS possible though, with using the down and up keys. But opening up the value I have not yet discovered.

I tried Enter (which closed the edit task window), space (does nothing), tab (does nothing), F2 (does nothing).

Does anyone have an idea?

For further explanation see my printscreen: http://prntscr.com/9euxd6. The downarrow I talk about are circled. So, I want to jump from connection 1 to 2 and alter the value by not clicking on the downarrow, but by using the keyboard only. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I also tried it, looks like it is really not possible!

Answer (score 0):

The below is copied from the *Informatica PowerCenter - 9.5.1 - Designer Guide* PDF.

### Using Shortcut Keys

  When editing a repository object, use shortcuts on the Ports or Columns tab.
  The following table lists the Designer shortcuts:
- Add a new field or port. `Alt+F`
- Cancel editing in a cell. `Esc`
- Select or clear a port type check box. `Space bar`
- Copy a row. `Alt+O`
- Copy text in a cell. `Ctrl+C`
- Cut a row. `Alt+C`
- To edit the text of a cell, press `F2`, then move the cursor to the location inside the cell.
- To find all combination and list boxes, type the first letter on the list.
- Find tables or fields in the workspace. `Ctrl+F`
- Move current row down. `Alt+W`
- Move current row up. `Alt+U`
- To open the Expression Editor from the expression field. Press `F2`, then press `F3`
- Paste a row. `Alt+P`
- Paste copied text into a cell. `Ctrl+V`
- Select the text of a cell. `F2`
- Validate the default value in a transformation. `Alt+V`

Comment: Thanks. Though informative and useful, it does not solve my current problem or don't I read it good enough? What I read is about transformations in the mapping designer and not the connections in the workflow designer (?).

Comment: @cybork Yes, my mistake, I misread your question and your link wasn't working for me, so this doesn't answer your question.  After looking at the documentation I have again and fooling around with the Workflow Manager shortcuts, it doesn't seem (at least in 9.6.1) that the Workflow Manager windows are designed in a way to be interacted with by just using the keyboard, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Let's hope someone tell us differently or some kind of hack.